# Problems with network input size

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I've been working on a character recognition program in MATLAB for sometime now and asked a couple questions on stackoverflow and received good feedback. So I figured I would try my luck again.

Problem: I'm getting this error in my train of the network.

"Input 1 size does not match net.inputs{1}.size."

I'm using the pictures below. I want to train my network using picture 1 to recognize the contents in picture 2. Before I can train the network, I pre-process the images. I wrote a program to extract each letter in the image and convert the image into a binary matrix. For example, if my grid for each letter is 10x10 then in my first image I would have a 10x10x4 matrix and the second image 10x10x2.

So now I have a target matrix 10x10x4 and an input matrix 10x10x2.

To train the network I need to reshape each 10x10 layer in the images so that each layer is "converted" to a row using the (:) operator. So now the target matrix has a size of 4x100 and the input matrix a size of 2x100.

Training:
It's my understanding that in order for the network to get trained to recognize the characters in the first image (targets), I need to train the network with those targets. Thusly, I use the following code.

```
[net, tr] = trainNNet(100, train, targets);
```

To perform the actual recognition, I simulate the net for each row in my input matrix and record the outputs using indices. So I step through the input matrix row-wise using a for/loop, simulate the network, and send the outputs to my findmatch function. This functions purpose is to find the rows in the targets where the input array matches. This is not really important to this error.

```
[r c d] = size(input);

for k = 1:d
    input = input(k,:);
    outputs = round(sim(net,input));

    [matched(:,k), ind(:,k)] = findmatch(outputs, targets);
end
```

I would like to know why I keep getting error "Input 1 size does not match net.inputs{1}.size."
This program works fine if I have only one letter in the input image. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image: targets]

[image: input]

Edit: I mentioned above that I used the (:) operator. This is a mistake. I use the following code to reshape the matrix into what I need.

```
[r c d] = size(input);
C = permute(input,[3 2 1]);
newinput = reshape(C,d,r*c,1);
```

So for example, given the following matrix:

```
input(:,:,1) = [1 2;3 4];
input(:,:,2) = [5 6;7 8];
input(:,:,3) = [9 10;11 12];
```

You would get:

```
newinput = [1,2,3,4;5,6,7,8;9,10,11,12];
```

Also, I made a mistake in stating that this works for one letter. This works for one letter **only** if I train the network with the letter I am wanting to recognize. I trained using,

```
[net, tr] = trainNNet(100, input, targets);
```

where input is would be 1x100 (for one letter).

Comment: Please show how you get from [10 10 4] to [4 100]. Could it be that you are doing a transpose that you shouldn't?

Comment: @Floris I've edited my post for the reshaping. I misstated that I used the (:) operator. I different coding for this which I've included with an example.

Comment: I believe I found a solution. I need to add rows of zeros to the input matrix so that it is the same size as the target/training matrix. I will have to test this out on different images.

Comment: Happy to hear it. If you have a solution that works, you might want to add it as the "correct" answer to the problem; then future visitors will see the problem and the answer. If you are still stuck, add more comments...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that I understand that to train the network I use the target values as targets and also as inputs, I found a way to make the simulation run.

For the inputs in the simulation, you have to add rows of zeros so that the resulting input matrix is the same size as the target matrix.